# Powershell + SMO issue: ScriptTransfer skips EXECUTE AS if ScriptTransfer not run once first?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I've run into a bizarre result when trying to script out a database.  The script works, but I see where there's an EXECUTE AS CALLER on a CLR SP that's not included, unless the ScriptTransfer() runs once first, even if that's redirected to out-null.

1. Run the below script against a database with a SP (ours is using a
   procedure with EXECUTE AS CALLER that calls a CLR with EXTERNAL
   NAME).
2. Comment out the line with the ScriptTransfer and OUT-NULL and change the
   filename
3. Run again
4. Compare files. You'll see that one has EXECUTE AS CALLER and the other doesn't.

Here's the script I'm running:

```
import-module sqlserver
$sql_server = "myservername"
$SMOServer = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server -ArgumentList "$sql_server"
$DBToScript = "mydbname" 

$db = $SMOServer.Databases[$DBToScript]
$create_database = $db.Script() -replace("\d+KB","100mb") 

##### And now the rest of the database

$transfer = new-object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Transfer #-ArgumentList $db
$transfer.Database = $db
$transfer.CopyAllObjects = $true
$transfer.CopySchema = $true
$transfer.ScriptTransfer() |out-null # for whatever reason this is necessary to script out the WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER in a CLR SP


cls
$transfer.CopyAllObjects = $true
$transfer.CopySchema = $true
$transfer.CopyAllSchemas= $true
$transfer.Options.Indexes = $true
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.filename = "c:\temp\backup\resultsa.sql"
$transfer.Options.ExtendedProperties= $true # yes, we want these
$transfer.Options.DRIAll= $true # and all the constraints 
$transfer.Options.Indexes= $true # Yup, these would be nice
$transfer.Options.Triggers= $true # This should be included when scripting a database
$transfer.Options.ScriptBatchTerminator = $true # this only goes to the file
$transfer.Options.IncludeHeaders = $false #pshaw
$transfer.Options.ToFileOnly = $true #no need of string output as well
$transfer.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = $false # not necessary but it means the script can be more versatile

$transfer.ScriptTransfer()
```